# Write variable to .sh script using echo

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write a variable to .sh script using echo, for example `echo "$dir" >test.sh` but it just copies the value of `$dir` as a text... instead, i want to see the the current value of `$dir` everytime i run the script.

EXAMPLE:

```
dir=~\first\
cat test.sh
```

outputs `ls -l ~\first\`

```
dir=~\second\
cat test.sh
```

outputs `ls -l ~\second\`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Escaping `$dir` as `\$dir` or `'$dir'` will write out the variable name instead of its value. If you want the script to print the value of `$dir` then you could write out an entire `echo` command.

```
echo 'echo "$dir"' > test.sh
```

Comment: I don't want it to print it... the script actually starts with `ls -l $dir` ... any way to still achieve what i asked?

Answer (score 0):

Then your script should contain something like this:

```
ls -l "$1" | ...
```

Then you can pass in the dir when you execute the script:

```
./script path/to/whatever
```

Comment: my script actually has to start with `ls -l $dir | ... ` , so any way to still achieve what i asked?

Comment: What are you asking?  If your script has to start with `ls -l $dir`, then it will start `ls -l $dir` and it won't start `ls -l foo` or `ls -l bar`, but you can easily get the behavior you (probably) want.  Describe the behavior you want.  If you want invocations of `cat` to print something other than `ls -l $dir` but you insist that the script start `ls -l $dir`, then you cannot get what you want.  But I suspect that what you are saying you want is *not* in fact what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate a cmd you can use $().

```
dir=~   
$( echo "ls -l $dir" > test.sh )
```

Comment: it's not working for me... my script starts with `ls -l $dir`

Comment: @UFC Insider  Why you don't use ls -l "$dir" > test.sh ?

Comment: because then you get just the output of the command. i want this command to be inside the script

Comment: @UFC Insider I have edit the response, maybe it's what you want.

Comment: still not working... run it the first time and then change `dir` and run again and you will get the previous value of `dir`

Comment: @UFCInsider It's not possible to change dynamically test.sh, when you dir change. They're two differents things.

Answer (score 0):

Staring into my crystal ball (that is, guessing wildly at what you're actually asking)....

if `dir=foo` in your current shell, and you want to invoke your script so that it lists the contents of `foo`, all you need to do is put `dir` in the environment.  That is, try one of:

```
dir=baz ./test.sh  # script runs with dir == baz
export dir
dir=foo
./test.sh  # script runs with dir == foo
dir=bar
./test.sh  # script runs with dir == bar
```

Comment: i'm not even there yet... before even running the script: let's say the current value of `dir` is `~/share/` then `cat test.sh` will print the script with that path, and then if i change the value fo `dir` to `~/newfolder/` and `cat test.sh` again - it will print the script with the new path

Comment: I guess your crystal ball is very logical. @UFCInsider - your post conflicts with your comment here. In your post you didn't want to echo the value of `$dir` to the shell script and here you want to see the value of the variable instead of the variable when you cat the shell script. I guess William Pursell will need 2 contradicting crystal balls.